# Show $Z$ is a Banach space with the norm $||z||=\sum^\infty_{j=1} |z_{2j}| + \bigg( \sum^\infty _{k=0} |z_{2k+1} |^2 \bigg)^\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $Z$ be the linear space of all sequences of complex numbers $z=(z_1 , z_2, z_3,..)$ such that $$ \sum^\infty _ {j=1} |z_{2j}|< \infty$$ and $$  \sum^\infty _{k=0} |z_{2k+1}|^2 < \infty$$

It can be shown that the formula $$||z||=\sum^\infty_{j=1} |z_{2j}| + \bigg( \sum^\infty _{k=0} |z_{2k+1} |^2 \bigg)^\frac{1}{2}$$
where $z =\{z_n\} \in Z$

defines a norm on $Z$.

My aim is to show that $Z$is a Banach space with this norm.

Proof:

We only have to show completeness.

So to show completeness I have been told it is sufficient to to observe that $z=(z_1 ,z_2,z_3,..) \in Z$ if and only if $z^{(1)}=(z_1, z_3, z_5,..) \in l^1$ and $z^{(2)}=(z_2, z_4, z_6,..) \in l^2$

> Why does $z^{(1)}=(z_1, z_3, z_5,..)$?
>
> And why does $z^{(2)}=(z_2, z_4, z_6,..)$?

Should it not be $z^{(1)}=(z_2, z_4, z_6,..)$? and $z^{(2)}=(z_1, z_3, z_5,..)$? because $l^1$ is defined as $z_{2j}$ and $l^2$ as $z_{2k+1}$

Comment: $z^{(1)}=(z_1,z_3,z_5,\ldots)$ is the _definition_ of the notation $z^{(1)}$ for the purpose of the hint. It's not something you can ask "why" about; it's just the symbol the author of the hint chose to use for $(z_1,z_3,z_5,\ldots)$ -- and similarly for $z^{(2)}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows by the following equality

$$ \Vert z \Vert = \Vert z^{(1)} \Vert_{l^1}+\Vert z^{(2)}\Vert_{l^2}$$

which is the definition of your norm.

Edit: As it has been poined out in the comments, the formula should be

$$ \Vert z \Vert = \Vert z^{(1)} \Vert_{l^1}+\Vert z^{(2)}\Vert_{l^2}.$$

And then we get $z\in Z $ iff $z^{(1)}\in l^2$ and $z^{(2)}\in l^1$.

Comment: ok but isn't $l^1$ defined as $z_{2j}$ so shouldn't $z^{(1)}=(z_2, z_4,z_6,..)$?

Comment: You are absolutely right. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: So does that mean the author whose answer I have quoted is wrong? Because I feel $z^{(1)}$ and $z^{(2)}$ should be swapped.

Comment: Yes, it's just a typo in the book. Sorry, for messing things up in the first place.

Comment: Thats ok, thanks for your help. The worrying this is this is from the solutions from a past paper!!